# using post_delete signal to delete a StreamItem

Tags: python, django, django-models, signals

Here is a model that i have created to create a news feed. A **StreamItem** is created using post_save() signal whenever an instance of the Models Fe and Event is created. Its all working fine. Now i want to delete any instance of **StreamItem** whenever instances of Fe and Event are deleted usinf post_delete() signal. Is it possible?

```
class StreamItem(models.Model):
 content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
 object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
 pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)

 content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

def get_rendered_html(self):
    template_name = 'streams/stream_item_%s.html' % (self.content_type.name)
    return render_to_string(template_name, { 'object': self.content_object }) 

def create_stream_item(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
# Check to see if the object was just created for the first time
 if 'created' in kwargs:
    if kwargs['created']:
        create = True

        # Get the instance's content type
        ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)

        pub_date = instance.pub_date

        if ctype.name == "photo":
            user = instance.album.user
        else:
            user = instance.user

        if create:
            StreamItem.objects.get_or_create(content_type=ctype, object_id=instance.id, pub_date=pub_date, user = user)

def delete_stream_item(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
  instance.delete()

# Send a signal on post_save for each of these models
for model in [Fe, Event ]:
    post_save.connect(create_stream_item, sender=model)
    post_delete.connect(delete_stream_item, sender=model)
```

Comment: i added this: post_delete.connect(delete_stream_item, sender=model) below post_save line and created a function delete_stream_item() with 'instance.delete()' in it. Didn't work.

Comment: please edit your post and put the code inside.

Comment: its just that much, i have deleted it from my project as it isn't working anyway.

Comment: yes but **please** edit your post and put the code in it. That's how you will get help here.

Comment: @Monique Hello! I think I am also going through the same tutorial and came to this situation. I just wanted to know, whether, the answer you selected is still working and without any problems? As the person who answered it warned about untested, I wanted to know, whether it is good for long run! I would really appreciate if you could help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `delete_stream_item()` function, `instance` is the object that has just been deleted, in your case either a `Fe` or `Event` instance. What you want is to retrieve all related `StreamItem` instances (using the `instance` ctype and pk) and delete them.

Warning: untested code:

```
def delete_stream_item(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
    ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)
    StreamItem.objects.filter(content_type=ctype, object_id=instance.id).delete()
```